# NSURLSession synchronous calls

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I am not sure seen a clean answer to this. I know how to use blocks, and completion handlers, however for this I cannot use them and need to call the method synchronously :

```
- (void)codePathWithURL:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    // Create session
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    config.URLCache = nil;
    config.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
    
    NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];


    // Using semaphores
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    NSURLSessionDataTask *sessionTask = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        responseData = data;
        httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        outError = error;
        
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    [sessionTask resume];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    // do something with data 
}
```

The problem I see here it is locks the main thread. How do I make this so that the main thread is not blocked?

Comment: *however for this I cannot use them*. I doubt that. There is always a way to handle the asynchronous behavior of `URLSession`. A semaphore is very bad practice. In this case the solution is pretty easy: Just move `// do something with data` into the completion block of the data task.

Comment: Yes, you should almost certainly lose the semaphores and stick with asynchronous patterns. I’d suggest you share why you think you need to do this synchronously and we might be able to help you solve that problem.

Comment: Using semaphores like that does make it synchronous.  Never do that on the main thread, though.   Usually the only reason to need it is to conform to an API requirement to return a value -- which is not the case in the example.  If you do need to return a value, the only way is to make the initial call to your method come from a background thread already.   Given the method you have, there doesn't seem to be a reason to avoid the usual NSURLSession completion blocks.

Comment: @vadian I had copy pasted the content of the code I had, the method signature needs to return the JSON object from the NSURLSession. Hence need the synchronous call

Comment: The return value of the method is `void` (no return value). Please learn to understand how asynchronous data processing works, it's not that difficult.

Comment: *yawn* - see the edits in my answer

Comment: “ I know how to use blocks, and completion handlers, however for this I cannot use them” ... again, why can’t you use them? This is precisely how we supply the network response to the calling routine. (And we wouldn’t use properties to pass the data back, but rather as parameters of our block.)

Comment: Unrelated, but it’s not advisable to create a new `NSURLSession` for each request. It’s inefficient and you’ll introduce memory usage problems. Create the `NSURLSession` once and use it for all the requests.

Answer (score -1):

Just a quick and dirty attempt to help you get going ... maybe use a condition?

```
// Call this on the background NOT on the main thread
- ( ... ) some message
{
    // Added stuff
    __block BOOL done = NO;      // ... use now to set data as well
    __block NSString * data;     // ... or whatever is needed
    NSCondition * condition = NSCondition.new;

    // Your original stuff
    // Create session
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    config.URLCache = nil;
    config.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
    
    NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
 NSURLSessionDataTask *sessionTask = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        responseData = data;
        httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        outError = error;

        // Added stuff
        condition.lock;
        done = YES;

        // Set data
        data = ... something ...        

        condition.broadcast;
        condition.unlock;
    }];

    [sessionTask resume];

    // New stuff
    condition.lock;
    while ( ! done )
    {
      condition.wait;
    }
    condition.unlock;

    // something like ...
    return data;
...
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted but anyhow, ```NSCondition``` gives you much more flexibility for when the task gets more complex which you do not have with semaphore which is why I suggest for this problem you use it.

Comment: Now also edited answer to illustrate the added flexibility.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216523/discussion-between-rob-and-skaak).